# Tracking which tables are being queried

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a SQL Oracle schema accessible to many other people. I'm not the first to use it and when I leave there will be someone using it after me.

There are many views that build on other views that I'm not aware exist, but are in use that were created before my time at my position. When organizing tables and columns I realized that if I do make any changes all these extremely important views would have errors since they use names that are not in the correct format.

All in all, I'm asking, how can I track which tables are being queried?

I've seen something online talking about a table that can track what I wanted, but I can't make sense of it, and it feels like some important stuff is missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you'd query `user_dependencies`, e.g.

```
SQL> select name, type, referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_Dependencies
  3  where referenced_owner = 'SCOTT'
  4  order by name;

NAME                  TYPE                 REFERENCED_NAME      REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------
APPLICATION_AGE_CHECK TRIGGER              APPLICATION          TABLE
APPLICATION_AGE_CHECK TRIGGER              PERSON               TABLE
F_TEST                FUNCTION             DATATEMPLATES        TABLE
MV_TEST               MATERIALIZED VIEW    MV_TEST              TABLE
MY_EVENTS             TYPE                 DEPT                 TABLE
<snip>
V_EMP                 VIEW                 DEPT                 TABLE
V_EMP                 VIEW                 EMP                  TABLE

23 rows selected.

SQL>
```

See the `v_emp` view info and its `FROM` clause - it joins `emp` and `dept` tables:

```
SQL> select text from user_views where view_name = 'V_EMP';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT d.deptno,
          d.dname,
          e.empno,
          NVL (e.ename, 'Missing person') ename
     FROM dept d LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.deptno = d.deptno
    WHERE d.deptno IN (30, 40)
```

That's what `user_dependencies` say:

```
NAME                  TYPE                 REFERENCED_NAME      REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------
V_EMP                 VIEW                 DEPT                 TABLE
V_EMP                 VIEW                 EMP                  TABLE
```

---

```
SQL> select * from v_emp;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME
---------- -------------- ---------- --------------
        30 SALES                7499 ALLEN
        30 SALES                7521 WARD
        30 SALES                7654 MARTIN
        30 SALES                7698 BLAKE
        30 SALES                7844 TURNER
        30 SALES                7900 JAMES
        40 OPERATIONS                Missing person

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```